# He would have stripped off two hundred yards of line

Tags: meaning

I have a problem with one sentence in a book, I am just reading - here it is:

> If he had been a fish, he would have stripped off two hundred yards of
>   line and leapt out of the water in an aquatic dance of delight.

What doess the part "he would have stripped off two hundred yards of line" mean? Could it be said in some other words?

Comment: It means he's powerful, energetic, and not easily restrained. That's 200 yards of *fishing line* which he would *strip, drag, pull* off the angler's reel in his (initial) break for freedom after being hooked. The *aquatic dance of delight* seems a bit weird, since it implies he's not worried about being eventually "reeled in" (caught and landed) when he's "played out" (exhausted from trying to avoid being reeled in).

Comment: @FF: Here's your answer to that bit of weirdness (https://books.google.com/books?id=MHPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT301&lpg=PT301&dq=aquatic+dance+of+delight&source=bl&ots=w42O0zL7eM&sig=Xz_pOhto78av2wUou_dh3QL7Srs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GT1eVaXwNvTasASj74HYCg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=aquatic%20dance%20of%20delight&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a metaphor eluding to a fish caught on a fisherman's line.

It comparing the situation at hand to a situation where a fish would swim away, breaking the fishing line and pulling 200 yards of line with him.